# How to fetch row value in PHP in Model

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch row values of the table whenever I click on that row. 
In this I have to display data of the table in row.. 
Whenever I click on the row I need to return other variables values of that row ..

Like When I am clicking on the subject I need to show Message of respective subject from database.

PHP Code to return row values from database.

This snippet will not run as it is PHP code(just add in the snipppet to good formatting )

[image]
[image]

In this image, Popup Model is not showing correct subject and message .. 
I need this particular subject and message in the popup

[image: Database Structure]

```
<?php
include('../config/conn.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM helpdesk where user_id='$user_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$sr=1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_id=$row["user_id"];
        $pooler_id=$row["pooler_id"];
        $date=$row["date"];
        $subject=$row["subject"];
        $req=$row['req_id'];
        $message=$row['message'];

        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM pooler where id='$pooler_id' ";
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                $username=$row1['user_name'];
                $email=$row1['email'];
            }
        }

        echo ' <tr>
                          <td>'.$sr.'</td>
                          <td>'.$username.'</td>
                          <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'.$subject.'</td>
                          <td>'.$date.'</td>


                        </tr>';
        $sr++;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Modal POP Code where Sender Name, Subject and Message should be displayed.

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"> <?php echo $username; ?> <br><br> <?php echo $subject;  ?>  </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>
      <?php 
      echo $message;
      ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can do this either by using jquery ajax call or by simple javascript. You just have to call javascript function on click of `$subject`.

Comment: I am not aware of javascript or jquery ..can u give an example

Answer (score 1):

In your html code

```
<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="showData('.$pooler_id.')">'.$subject.'</td>
```

Please pass your unique id in javascript function.

Modal

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"> 
      <span id="user_name"><?php echo $username; ?></span> <br><br> <span id="subject"><?php echo $subject;  ?></span>  </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p id="msg">
      <?php 
      echo $message;
      ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Script

```
<script>
function showData(pooler_id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: POST,
        url : 'some_file.php',
        data: {pooler_id: pooler_id},
        success: function(response){
            var resp = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#user_name').html(resp.user_name);
            $('#subject').html(resp.subject);
            $('#msg').html(resp.msg);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

In some_file.php

```
$pooler_id = $_POST['pooler_id'];
//get records of your primary key json_decode it
//get details from database
//this will be result fetched from database
$responseData['user_name'] = $name;
$responseData['subject'] = $subject;
$responseData['msg'] = $msg;


echo json_decode($responseData);
```

Comment: do I need to fetch data from database in some_file.php .. ?? and what is json_decode ??

Comment: Yes you need to fetch data from database. For json decode see my updated answer

Comment: it is still showing the last value of the message and subject variable .. Please check the database structure .

Comment: Pass req_id in javascript function. You will get result as you want.

Comment: echo req_id in table and check which req_id you are getting in file some_file.php. You need to debug it. Coz the code I gave works fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95894/discussion-between-rahul-dambare-and-apb).

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is not resolved yet and you try to avoid usage of JSON:

You could try to add an individual id (e.g. `$sr`) to your `<div class="modal-content">` id property and `<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'.$subject.'` call in view. Got this from http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Maybe this works for you.

Add to your PHP code `<a href="#modal-content-'.$sr.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'.$subject.'`:

```
<?php
include('../config/conn.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM helpdesk where user_id='$user_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$sr=1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_id=$row["user_id"];
        $pooler_id=$row["pooler_id"];
        $date=$row["date"];
        $subject=$row["subject"];
        $req=$row['req_id'];
        $message=$row['message'];

        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM pooler where id='$pooler_id' ";
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                $username=$row1['user_name'];
                $email=$row1['email'];        //note this value is never used

                echo ' <tr>
                           <td>'.$sr.'</td>
                           <td>'.$username.'</td>
                           <td>
                               <a href="#modal-content-'.$sr.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'.$subject.'</a>
                           </td>
                           <td>'.$date.'</td>
                       </tr>';
                $sr++;
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

and to your Modal `<div class="modal-content-<?php echo $sr; ?>">`:

```
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content-<?php echo $sr; ?>">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> 
        <span id="user_name"><?php echo $username; ?></span> <br><br> <span id="subject"><?php echo $subject;  ?></span>  </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="msg"><?php echo $message; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No its not working .. it still shows last entry of the table

Comment: I got it. It does show only the last entry of the table because in PHP code, the output formatting part is outside the while loop. I have changed my code above so that your table is now build within the while loops.